# Ensuring that a particular directory hierarchy exists in the file system (creating if it necessary)

Tags: java, string, memory, arraylist

The problem: I need to ensure that a particular directory hierarchy exists in the file system, and create it if it doesn't.

I know that there is the method `File.mkdirs()` however the javadocs for that method indicate that it could fail creating some or all of the directories necessary to complete the path given.

To get around that, I made a method that takes a String representing the path and parses it into the individual parts, storing them into an `ArrayList<String>`.  A second method would then go through and build the directories up, making sure that each directory and sub directory existed.

The problem is, the actual program runs out of memory when trying to loop through and break up the string into its individual parts.  I know it's not the function; it works perfectly on its own in a JUnit test, and the program itself isn't very memory intensive.  At this point, it's just set directories up and stored them into a "DataBank" class - nothing big, just a class storing a bunch of strings.

I'd like to figure out what's causing the problem; I can reply with the different classes in effect at the point the code stops.

However, a simpler solution might just be to use `File.mkdirs()`.  What would cause `File.mkdirs()` to not create directories?  Would it just be insufficient permissions?

I'd like to simplify the process if I can, instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.  At the same time, though, I know that the program should not be running out of memory - I'm storing Strings and performing file operations, nothing super intensive.

Comment: You say: *"The problem is, the actual program runs out of memory when trying to loop through and break up the string into its individual parts."* Next you say: *"I know it's not the function; it works perfectly on its own in a JUnit test*.  Then your first sentence can't be accurate (can it?).  In any event, we need you to post the code in order to help.

Comment: You are right that you can just use `File.mkdirs()`.  You're not going to 'outsmart' it by creating the directories individually - it's just saying that it could fail because of some i/o error (permissions most likely).  If `mkdirs()` failed, your attempt to do it individually would also fail.

Comment: Reduce your question to the few lines of code that are failing, ideally providing a test case. No one cares about your life story or your app - it's irrelevant to the actual problem, and a lot noise on the page. Read about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Just a pointer: besides the obvious need to show your code, you don't need to give us paragraphs of context for your application if it's completely irrelevant to the question (and in many cases, might actually make people want to help *less*).

Comment: Thank you guys for the helpful comments.  

@GregKopff - I should have been more clear.  When I invoke the static function with parameters from Main, the program runs out of memory.  However, I think it was an environment issue, which I corrected.  Although, I did just switch to using File.mkdirs() - there's a lot less headache, now.

Bohemian - Thanks for the SSCCE link; I'll make sure my future posts  conform to that.

Mark - Thanks for the tip.  I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I wanted to upvote initially because the question is useful. However, it then replaced with manual implementaion failure, which has nothing to do with the subject of path creation. Go ****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **However, a simpler solution might just be to use File.mkdirs(). What would cause File.mkdirs() to not create directories? Would it just be insufficient permissions?**

`File.mkdirs()` could fail for any of the reasons that `File.mkdir()` fails (except for failing due to the parent directory not existing (for obvious reasons)).

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29):

> `public boolean mkdirs()`
>
> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. **Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories**

The bold bit is a clue that `mkdirs()` is just a shortcut for multiple calls to `mkdir()`.

[Here's what `mkdirs()` does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/File.java#File.mkdirs%28%29) - it effectively calls `mkdir()` up the directory hierarchy:

```
public boolean mkdirs() {
    if (exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (mkdir()) {
        return true;
    }
    File canonFile = null;
    try {
        canonFile = getCanonicalFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    File parent = canonFile.getParentFile();
    return (parent != null && (parent.mkdirs() || parent.exists()) &&
            canonFile.mkdir());
}
```